# Styling the UI elements of Qt Designer through Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, style, css, qt-designer

I am trying to style the UI elements built through Qt Designer(drag-drop) via the plugin for QGIS.

I have tried to import 'style.css' to the plugin main file, but it is not reflecting the changes in the plugin .
Here is the code :

```
class ABTDModel:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        app = QApplication.instance()
        app.setStyleSheet('C:/Users/FTL1KOR/Desktop/Github/Network_Processing/style.css')
```

In style.css , this is the code :

```
QDialog{
  background-color: red;
}
```

It doesn't throw any error, but it is not reflecting any changes in the Plugin's UI.

Comment: Probably one for Stack Overflow. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504421/how-to-apply-style-sheet-to-a-custom-widget-in-pyqt/52529873#52529873) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506787/reading-pyqt-stylesheet-from-external-qss-file). And maybe you don't want set it on the whole app, just your plugin dialog (`self.dlg`).